# Visual Studio suddenly breaking on ALL internal (catched!) exceptions of all assemblies in the whole application

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, break

Meaning that the application breaks 10s of times in a single page load. I think I hit a shortcut or setting accidently - how can I reset this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or go to **Debug** > **Windows** > **Exception Settings** to open the Exception Settings window and click the "Restore" to default settings" button in the toolbar.

See [Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019):

[image: Screenshot exception settings]

Comment: I panicked (deadline) and reset my whole Visual Studio settings - that seemed to work :) Thanks for your quick reply!